# Click event fired multiple times on iPad

Tags: ionic3

I’m developing an Ionic Application and I’m facing some strange issues with my iDevice.

Whenever I pres any button (no matter if it’s form some ionic component or some jQuery plugin), the application fires the click event 5 times at once. I have a calendar, and I switch from day 18th Sept to 13th September, or when I click on a “create” of some entity my App has, I create it 5 times. This doesn’t happen on Android, neither on ionic serve/ionic lab.

Can anyone give me some hint about what can be wrong about all this?

Thanks in advance.
Pavel.

Comment: And your `code`...?

Comment: A +60 pages project, with +80 imports at the app.module.ts (I'm not using Lazy Loading). Which piece of code do I exactly need to show?

Comment: Which `code` do you have an issue?

Comment: It happens every time I push a button that loads some new page, not at any special page o any special button at all.

Comment: Then put that button's and related page's code.

Answer (score 0):

Changing all the `(click)` events to `(tap)` ones seems to solve the issue.